# Bootstrap - Control focus wrapped by dots only on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why does every control on IE gets wrapped by dots when it gets focused?
I'm using Bootstrap, I didn't edited the style scripts, they are default.
The textbox from Google it's very similar to my textbox, but it does not get wrapped by dots.
How can I hide these dots?

Here's the screenshot that shows the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMw7y.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be removed using `outline:0;` in your CSS

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  outline:0;
}
```

More information on CSS-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/